# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I have a mySQL database and i'm trying to pass the register information into server.js and write it to the database i've been trying to do this for a few days now and can't get it right can anyone help me... here is the code..

```
app.get('/users/add', (req, res) => {
const firstName = req.body.firstName;
lastName = req.body.lastName;
userName = req.body.userName;
password = req.body.password;
email = req.body.email;
const INSERT_USERS_QUERY =
  'INSERT INTO users (' +
  `firstName, lastName, userName, password, email) values(
    ${firstName},${lastName},${userName},${password},${email})`;

connection.query(INSERT_USERS_QUERY, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.send('Successfuly added user');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/users/add'
```

You are using a **Get** request and you are trying to access req.body, you can access req.body only in post request.

You should change it to this and when you send the request you should add a body in it too :

```
app.post('/users/add'
```

Comment: I tried that it didn't work.. I'm writing this in jsx not tax cause I noticed I can't use async and await in jsx... I'm using vscode any suggestions